# Azure monitor external systems

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring

I want to monitor external systems using azure monitor. Is it possible?

For example, I have on-prem Linux server with mysql DB, can I monitor the server and its DB like availability, errors,...?

Comment: The answer is yes. You have already tagged Azure monitor there. Why don't you read this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs

Comment: For sure, I already had a look before asking the question but didn't find what I'm looking for. why did you consider that I didn't look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use “Azure Monitor agent” that is explained  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/azure-monitor-agent-overview?tabs=CLI1%2CCLI2).  Would recommend you to use Azure Monitor Log Analytics agent as instructed  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-windows). The reason for it is “[Azure Monitor Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/azure-monitor-agent-overview?tabs=CLI1%2CCLI2)”  as informed in  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/azure-monitor-agent-overview?tabs=CLI1%2CCLI2#current-limitations)  section, currently only Azure VMs are supported and on-premises VMs, virtual machine scale sets, Arc for Servers, Azure Kubernetes Service, and other compute resource types are currently not supported.

Next, If you have “[Azure Monitor Log Analytics agent on Windows machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-windows)” then you may have to check below things:

1. As explained  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking), Change Tracking and Inventory requires linking a Log Analytics workspace to your Automation account so I recommend you to double check it. For a definitive list of supported regions, see  [Azure Workspace mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/region-mappings). The region mappings don't affect the ability to manage VMs in a separate region from your Automation account.
2. Follow  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/change-tracking#windows)  troubleshooting steps in your case (i.e., if you don't see any Change Tracking and Inventory results for Windows machines that have been enabled for the feature).
3. As mentioned  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking), note that currently Change Tracking and Inventory currently is experiencing the following issue w.r.t Windows environment: Hotfix updates aren't collected on Windows Server 2016 Core RS3 machines.